# Spark NoSuchElementException: None.get in Spark Streaming app

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've got a Spark Streaming app, which worked fine just until yesterday. 
Now I'm facing this error after launching it:

```
> ERROR Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (org.apache.spark.executor.Executor:91)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It never gave me this error before. How can I solve this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please add the line of code at which you are getting this error. Also, checkout `getOrElse` method in scala.

Comment: The line of code is that in which a JavaSparkContext is launched for a second time. I set the AllowMultipleContext = true but it didn't work. How do I manage this?

Comment: Though that option exists, it's better not to use multiple `SparkContext` in the same app.

Comment: I need it because one is a StreamingContext and the other one is a simple SparkContext. Do you think thy  cannot live together?

Comment: As long as you are creating the `StreamingContext` using the `SparkContex`, it's fine. see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623109/can-sparkcontext-and-streamingcontext-co-exist-in-the-same-program)

Comment: "using" the SparkContext? What does it mean? How could I prevent this error?