# DataFrame to RDD[(String, String)] conversion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis, apache-kafka, databricks

**I want to convert an `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` to `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]` in Databricks.** Can anyone help?

*Background* (and a better solution is also welcome): I have a Kafka stream which (after some steps) becomes a 2 column data frame. I would like to put this into a Redis cache, first column as a key and second column as a value.

*More specifically* the type of the input is this: `lastContacts: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [serialNumber: string, lastModified: bigint]`. I try to put into Redis as follows:

```
sc.toRedisKV(lastContacts)(redisConfig)
```

The error message looks like this:

```
notebook:20: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]
sc.toRedisKV(lastContacts)(redisConfig)
```

I already played around with some ideas (like function `.rdd`) but none helped.

Comment: Can you convert your dataframe directly to a RDD?  lastContacts.map(r => (r.getString(0), r.getString(1)).rdd

Comment: Thanks; somewhat better. Now the error message is this: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();

Comment: Maybe you can use sc.start(), sc.awaitTermination() and lastContacts.foreachRDD ... https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work as is. Error message: value start is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Comment: you can create a streamingcontext through a sparkcontext https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623109/can-sparkcontext-and-streamingcontext-co-exist-in-the-same-program

Comment: It does not work as is. Can you please show me an example code? I.e. what to import etc. Thanks!

Comment: Added a small sample on your other question about streaming (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343792/call-a-function-with-each-element-a-stream-in-databricks/)

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up! I answered there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use df.map(row => ...) to convert the dataframe to a RDD if you want to map a row to a different RDD element.

For example:

```
val df = Seq(("table1",432),
      ("table2",567),
      ("table3",987),
      ("table1",789)).
      toDF("tablename", "Code").toDF()

    df.show()

    +---------+----+
|tablename|Code|
+---------+----+
|   table1| 432|
|   table2| 567|
|   table3| 987|
|   table1| 789|
+---------+----+

    val rddDf = df.map(r => (r(0), r(1))).rdd // Type:RDD[(Any,Any)]

    OR

    val rdd = df.map(r => (r(0).toString, r(1).toString)).rdd  //Type: RDD[(String,String)]
```

Please refer https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/106500/error-in-spark-streaming-kafka-integration-structu.html regarding **AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()**

You need to wait for the termination of the query using query.**awaitTermination()**
To prevent the process from exiting while the query is active.

Comment: @Csaba Faragó : Please let me know if it didn't work. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The conversion problem has been solved, but the streaming problem not yet. (Indeed, this is the final solution, as the question was about the conversion; the streaming question will be a new one if I cannot solve.)