# Azure DataBricks Stream foreach fails with NotSerializableException

Tags: apache-spark, redis, apache-kafka, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to continuously elaborate rows of a dataset stream (originally initiated by a Kafka): based on a condition I want to update a Radis hash. This is my code snippet (`lastContacts` is the result of a previous command, which is a stream of this type: `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [serialNumber: string, lastModified: long]`. This expands to `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]`):

```
class MyStreamProcessor extends ForeachWriter[Row] {
  override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
    true
  }

  override def process(record: Row) = {
    val stringHashRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(("lastContact", record(1).toString)))
    sc.toRedisHASH(stringHashRDD, record(0).toString)(redisConfig)
  }

  override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}
}

val query = lastContacts
  .writeStream
  .foreach(new MyStreamProcessor())
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

I receive a huge stack trace, which the relevant part (I think) is this: `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter`

Could anyone explain why this exception occurs and how to avoid? Thank you!

This question is related to the following two:

- [DataFrame to RDD[(String, String)] conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55335877/dataframe-to-rddstring-string-conversion/55347332#55347332)
- [Call a function with each element a stream in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343792/call-a-function-with-each-element-a-stream-in-databricks/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark Context is not serializable.

*Any implementation of ForeachWriter must be serializable because each task will get a fresh serialized-deserialized copy of the provided object. Hence, it is strongly recommended that any initialization for writing data (e.g. opening a connection or starting a transaction) is done after the open(...) method has been called, which signifies that the task is ready to generate data.*

In your code, you are trying to use spark context within process method,

```
override def process(record: Row) = {
    val stringHashRDD = sc.parallelize(Seq(("lastContact", record(1).toString)))
    *sc.toRedisHASH(stringHashRDD, record(0).toString)(redisConfig)*
  }
```

To send data to redis, you need to create your own connection and open it in the open method and then use it in the process method.

Take a look how to create redis connection pool. https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/redislabs/provider/redis/ConnectionPool.scala

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and sorry being delayed with the reaction. So if I understand correctly the solution could be practically implementing an own Redis connection method. This is not really nice solution; however, you response answers my question.